# PHP with pagination - I know I am almost there

Tags: php

I have created a search of a database that produces an HTML table to display the results. The results display an article title, which is hyperlinked to its location on the server, as well as the author of the article.

All works fine until I set up pagination using an online script. The pagination returns 25 results, with navigation to next pages. All results are fine in first page, but it seems the search query is not carried to the other pages.

If another page is selected "2, 3, ..., last" it displays information from the entire mysql table, not the queried data.

I have set up sessions to carry the search term, but it does not seem to be working. I believe the issue is in my code used to display results.

The script I used had this as an example to display results, but I cannot get it to work with my current "while loop statement"  **EXAMPLE BELOW**

```
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    }
?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

This is the last bit of script **I HAVE USED**, used to display the data.

```
<h2>Results</h2>

<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>Title</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>Author</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
<?php do { ?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo  '<a href="' . 'http:filelocation' . $row['pdf_path'] . '" target="_new">' .$row['pdf_title'] . '</a>'; 
 ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['author'] ;?></td>
  <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['pages']; ?></div></td>
  </tr>
<?php } 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))

 ?>
```

I am using a "do while" statement to get data and display results, but do not know how to add the "while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))" with proper syntax.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using the right `LIMIT` sentence in your query? I mean, how are you getting the data?

Comment: This is the query statement ("select * from $tbl_name where author like '%$term%' or     pdf_title like '%$term%' LIMIT $start, $limit");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your search query is `$searchquery`

```
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?searchquery=$searchquery&page=$next\">next �</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you Simon. I have tried this, but it still results in the linked page giving all data in the table, not queried data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting that values from a search form, so:

- Are you using GET method?
- How are you keeping the parameters you are filtering your data by?

Then in your search.php you need to get the submitted parameters, which will be in the `$_GET`  variable and then filter your data again.

Comment: Value comes from a form using POST.
I am using $_SESSION['term'] = $_POST['term'];

Should I change this to GET?

Comment: Still not getting the data, even with GET instead of POST